# multiple String literal in flex

Tags: regex, string, lex, flex-lexer, string-literals

I'm using flex to parse a whole buncha stuff, but I hit a roadbloack when I tried to detect two string literals on the same line.

my regex:

```
["].*["]
```

heres what I mean:

```
"cats" < "dogs"
```

is being recognized as one long string

```
cats" < "dogs
```

Why is flex only considering the two most outer quotations, instead of making two separate sets?
Im certain that the problem lies in my regex, so what I'm essentially asking is:

How do I write a regex that, in this scenario, would recognize the tokens STRING, LESS, STRING  as opposed to just STRING?

Comment: You should include your regex, really. Otherwise, it is hard to know why it doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're using a pattern like this:

```
["].*["]              { return STRING; }
```

Or perhaps

```
["].*?["]             { return STRING; }
```

The first one won't work because flex always takes the longest match, and the match using the last <kbd>"</kbd> is obviously longer. The second one would be correct in a regular expression library which implements non-greedy repetition, but flex does not; in flex, `.*?` is just an optional `.*` (which is to say, the `?` is a no-op.)

What you actually want is to match strings of characters other than quotes. So you can just say that:

```
["][^"]*["]           { return STRING; }
```

`[^"]` will match a newline character, unlike `.`. If you didn't want multi-line strings, you'd have to use `[^"\n]`.

Obviously, the above doesn't allow <kbd>"</kbd> to appear in strings, which sooner or later will be annoying. Two popular solutions to this problem are (C-style) to allow <kbd>\</kbd> to "escape" the next character: (`"a \" in a string"`)

```
["]([^"]|\\.)*["]     { return STRING; }
```

or (SQL-style) to require that internal <kbd>"</kbd> be doubled: ("a "" in a string"`)

```
["]([^"]|["]["])*["]  { return STRING; }
```

Comment: I put the edit in. This should help future readers with the same question.
You hit the nail right on the head. I wasn't expecting there to be such a simple elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not sure why flex is doing what it is. But to answer your question about how to write the RegEx to detect this case:

```
/^\"(?=.*[\"].*[\"].*[\"])(?=.*[\<]).+?\"$/
```

This RegEx will match on a line that meets these criteria:

- Starts and ends with quotation marks
- Contains 3 quotation marks after the first one (indicating that the line contains two strings)
- Contains exactly one angle bracket

Because I don't know if these are exactly the criteria you need to match, I'll break down this regex and some important components.

After checking for the first quotation mark, this lookahead subroutine is parsed:

`(?=.*[\"].*[\"].*[\"])`

This checks ahead in the RegEx subject to see if there are another three quotation marks. It matches anything followed by a quotation mark, three times. You could modify this to check for more or less quotation marks by adding or removing the `.*[\"]` part.

Next, we have another lookahead subroutine:

`(?=.*[\<])`

This checks that there is at least one angle bracket between the first and last quotation marks. If you'd like to check for other operations, you could add them inside the square brackets in `[\<]`, like so: `[\<\>\=\+]`.

Finally, we match any character one or more times with `.+?`, followed by the final quotation mark: `\"`.

It's important to note that lookahead subroutines don't actually move through the string as they do their checking. For instance, if we use the regex `/a(?=a)a/`, it will only match two consecutive 'a' characters, not three.

This is why the first lookahead I mention above tries to find 3 quotation marks after the first.

Maybe not the answer you were looking for, but I hope that this helps a little bit.

Comment: flex doesn't implement lookahead assertions. (Also, OP just wants to match a single string.)

Comment: I appreciate that you explained this in such a detailed. Even if you didn't give me answer that I'm looking for, you familiarized me with some new tools that are related to my problem.